# COUNTIF only if header of column contains specific text

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to write a function in excel (without using vba/macros if possible), to count the number of remaining work days for each employee for the month, from the first of the month to a date I enter into A1. The problem is, the scheduling file I use starts on a Monday every time, so if the month begins on a Friday, there are 4 days from the previous month on the page and the same could happen at the end of the month if the month doesn't end exactly on a Saturday.

In row 6, I have the dates (formatted as 28-Sep-2015), and from rows 9 and below, I have employee names and whether or not they're scheduled to work on the days directly above in row 6. I'm looking to count the number of times the word "WORKING" appears in the row for each given employee, but **only** to count it if the header in row 6 contains "Sep". I don't want to count any times "WORKING" appears if it comes from the past month or the upcoming month. (Also, no one works Sundays, so Sundays are skipped.)

I'll try to show an example of set up here.. hopefully it can help:

A1: 28-Sep-2015

A6-H6: Employee, 28-Sep-2015, 29-Sep-2015,30-Sep-2015, 1-Oct-2016, 2-Oct-2016, 3-Oct-2016

A9-H9: George, WORKING, OFF, WORKING, WORKING, WORKING, WORKING

So for this small example, the result should only be 2 working days, since George only works twice from 28 Sep to the end of the month.

I've been searching for how to do this for a few days now, but nothing seems to work when I try it. Please help!

Comment: You need to use countifs (with an 's') function to acheive that

Comment: @Seb How could I apply countifs in a way that could automatically work for every month in question? Meaning in this example I could manually choose the range that contains only September dates, but with every month the range would change, based on what day of the week the month begins and ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2007 and later than use this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$6:$G$6,"<="&EOMONTH($A$1,0),$A$6:$G$6,">="&DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),1),$A9:$G9,"=WORKING")
```

Comment: That's much closer than I've gotten up until now! But how could I adjust that to disregard the WORKING dates before the date set in A1? There is always the whole month on the sheet, which could also include a few days from the previous month, if they are past the Monday containing the first of the month in question. (In Sep 2015 there would be one day in the beginning, Aug 31, because it's that first Monday.)

Comment: @NanaPria then add criteria to be greater than the first of the month.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why this change makes any difference, but I changed the function you wrote a little. What you offered made sense when I tried to understand what it was doing, but it was still counting from the beginning of the month, even with the date added in. I changed it to   
`=COUNTIFS($A$6:$G$6,"<="&EOMONTH($A$1,0),$A$6:$G$6,">="&$A$1,$A9:$G9,"=WORKING") `  
And now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your requirement, It makes sense now.. Please consider marking as correct.